# Vb.net updating datagrid view problems

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i build a p.o.s and i tried to update the datagridview but every time i enter new entry i dot get the data grid view i tried to refresh it the datagrid but no success.

```
   Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into baza.artikli(barkod,naziv,kupovna,prodazna,opis,kolicina,ddv,makpr) values ('" & TextBoxBarkod.Text & "','" & TextBoxNaziv.Text & "','" & kupovna & "','" & prodazna & "','" & TextBoxOpis.Text & "','" & TextBoxKolicina.Text & "','" & ddv & "','" & makpr & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
```

how can i update the dataset from here i use it with mysql

Comment: There ***are many problems here***, it's hard to tell... I would first research into how to **properly** query the database first ...

Comment: I updated the question SIR

Comment: I understand, but now this ***does not have anything to do with updating a DataGridView***. Before you edited the question you had much more code than this. I would recommend updating this question with all relevant code in question so we can better assist you.

Comment: Start by using SQL parameters.  The code will be easier to read, wont force data type conversions and will be safer among many other things

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill dataset and show data after in grid here is an example:

I have used MS SQL SERVER, you can use MySql

```
 Public Function FillDataSet(query As String, ByVal ParamArray para() As Object) As DataTable

     dim _transaction As SqlTransaction
     Dim _command As SqlCommand

    _command = New SqlCommand(query, yourConnection)

    _ds = New DataSet
    _sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter(_command )
    _command.Transaction = _transaction

    For i = 0 To para.Count - 1
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & i, para(i))
    Next

    _sqlda.Fill(_ds)

   return _ds.tables(0)

   End Function
```

call it

```
 dataGridView1.datasource = FillDataSet(yourQuery, yourParam)
```